# Using do/does and be(is/are) in the same question

Tags: grammar

I'm not a native English speaker.
We were supposed to use the verb *be* instead of the verb *belong* using possessive pronouns.

The question is

- *Do those toys belong to her?*

The answer given by some is

- *Do those toys are hers?*

Isn't it simpler to say:

- *Are those toys hers?*

Sorry for bringing a confusing issue and not stating it properly.
Thanks a lot. I appreciate your concern very much. I enjoy learning English.

Comment: Welcome to ELL Exchange!  You are correct.  The proper form of this question would be either the original or *Are those toys hers?*  The alternative that you offered, *Do those toys are hers?* is ungrammatical; it's just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As Jason said, you are correct:

> *Do those toys are hers?

Is ungrammatical. The correct form of this question is:

> Are those toys hers?

or

> Whose are those toys?

When we ask questions in English we use [subject-auxiliary inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion#In_questions). In the sentence: *These toys belong to her* when we ask a question the auxiliary *do* is inverted with the subject *these toys*. The verb *belong* is called the main verb.

The difference between ***Do** those toys **belong** to her?* and ***Are** those toys hers?* comes from the difference in the nature (in lack of a better word) of verbs *to be* and *to belong*.

**[Be](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/be)** is the [copula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28linguistics%29) in this sentence. With copular *be* we don't use an auxiliary to form questions - the inversion occurs between the verb *to be* and the subject and you get:

> (S) Those toys (V) are hers.
>
> (V) Are (S) those toys hers?

---

Aside: Whether *to be* as a copula is an auxiliary verb is apparently a matter of linguistic debate, but in asking questions and forming negations it follows the same rules as an auxiliary.